# Как сгенерировать .jar библиотеку,посредством существующего проекта Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, export

Я не **java** разработчик,так что для меня не понятно,как можно достичь поставленной задачи(а именно создать свою либу .jar ).

На текущий момент,успешно создал андроид приложение(IDE Android Studio), в проект так же,я добавил нативную библиотеку.
[image: NativeLibb]

Реализовал MainActivity(вызов API камеры,добавлены всякие контролы и тд) и самое важное, я создал свой **кастомный класс**, в котором используются классы\методы из добавленной либы(см. скрин выше).
Этот кастомный класс,мне нужно использовать в другом проекте.
[image: Structure of project]

Проблема заключается в том, что не совсем понятно, как это все добро **упаковать** в .jar библиотеку.

Я пробовал делать следующее(посредством **build.gradle**):

```
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete){
    delete 'release/MyCustomLib.jar'
}
task exportJar(type: Copy){
    from('src/main')
    into('release/') include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'MyCustomLib.jar')
}
exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

К сожалению не сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Android приложение может распространятся только в виде APK. Потому что оно приложение.

Если же Вы написали какой-то модуль, который желаете распространять для использования в других Android проектах, то создайте в Android Studio модуль Library и перенестите весь код и ресурсы туда. После компилирования получите на выходе AAR-файл, который по сути есть Android библиотека.

В JAR можно запаковать только код (классы), если у Вас есть хоть один ресурс (строки, картинки и т.п.), то только AAR.

Comment: благодарю за отклик. Да,мне нужен именно .jar,потому что такие ресурсы как drawable/layouts и тд, мне НЕ нужны. По сути только класс,в котором есть логика(А сама логика, использует другую нативную либу,то бишь как я описал в главном вопросе). Попробую сделать проект  Library. А как через build.grandle заэкспортить нужный мне класс?)

Comment: Как я понимаю, в модуле Library должен заработать тот код из build.gradle, что Вы приводите в вопросе.

Comment: Я уже делал .jar(но именно всего проекта). Теперь сделал иначе, тип проекта Module(в этот модуль,я добавил нативную библиотеку,переписал немного градл и все заработало,т.е. в модуле создал класс,который использует нативную либу,все отлично,компилится и модуль видит эту либу. ),затем все упаковал в .jar и все равно,в том проекте,где  использую(а это Xamarin), этот класс почему то не доступен.  Хотя если открыть через .JAR Viewer, можно заметить что этот класс существует(и он кстати имеет модификатор доступа как паблик) http://i.stack.imgur.com/hWzTA.png

Comment: Xamarin работает на своей VM, Java классы к ней не прикрутишь.

Comment: Там смесь далвика + своя ВМ. Все можно прикрутить. :)